# Calculating average commute time within 15 miles of city center using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

I am using ArcMap.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the average commute time to work within 15 miles of the city center (and then map it in a form of continuous symbols (red to green gradient) with a legend, scale and everything. That would be called “average commute times to work).

Could you help me for the first part of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You need [Network Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_Network_Analyst/004700000001000000/) extension for ArcGIS. It has a function called [Service Area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Service_area_analysis/004700000048000000/) that will do roughly what you want.

The accuracy will depend on how good your data on the average speed of your road links is. If you also want to look at commute times including public transportation that that becomes a far harder problem, and not one that ArcGIS is really very well equipped to answer.